# Are these 2 sentences same. minor different, moderately different substantially different or completely different

Tags: differences

1 (.plant if Syria obtained a nuclear power reactor and needed fresh fuel...) or2.(plant if Syria obtained a nuclear capacity reactor and needed fresh fuel..).

Comment: Well, neither is a sentence. There is no such thing as a "capacity" reactor and your options are what is known as [*begging the question*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't sentences, but the difference seems to be "nuclear power reactor" versus "nuclear capacity reactor"

I don't believe there is such a thing as a "nuclear capacity reactor".  A "nuclear power reactor" is a nuclear reactor engineered to be an electric power plant; some reactors are intended primarily to transmute elements.  Nuclear capability indicates that one has the resources and technology to build nuclear devices (including reactors).  The capacoty of a power plant is the peak sustained generating ability.